# Infinitesimal generators and conserved quantities (Schrodinger type evolution)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, applied-mathematics, hamiltonian-mechanics

First, I'm no expert in symmetry analysis of evolution equations and so I apologize if this post is a bit of a cobble. The question I have is about the evolution of $\psi: \mathbb{R}^{1+1}\to \mathbb{C}$ given by

$i \psi_{t} + \psi_{xx} + \frac{1}{2}|\psi|^{2} \psi + \lambda \left(\left[|\psi|^{2} \psi\right]_{xx} + |\psi|^{4} \psi \right) =0, \, \, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,

which could be thought of as a fully nonlinear perturbation of the cubic focusing nonlinear Schrodinger equation, which has a well-known and rich structure endowed by complete integrability.

I've given this equation and its complex conjugate to the [SYM software for Mathematica](http://www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn/). To ease the computational burden, I've run the procedure for various $\lambda$. Doing so reveals that $\partial_{t}$ and $\partial_{x}$ are Lie point symmetries for the evolution. Given the form of the PDE, this seems sensible. I've found in several locations that time translation invariance conserves the system "energy/Hamiltonian" and that spatial translation invariance conserves "mass/momentum." Decoding these statements is where I'm having problems.

Let's concentrate on the time translation symmetry (TTS). I'm aware of [Geometric structure of NLS evolution](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1844) and can generalize the process to include the power term, but I don't see a way to incorperate the fully nonlinear term.

1. What is the notion of "energy/Hamiltonian" that is conserved by TTS?
2. Supposing that I could derive a Hamiltonian functional, is this the quantity which is conserved by TTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps part of your question could be phrased as follows. Does there exists a (formally defined) functional $S_1[\psi,\bar{\psi}] = \int dt\,dx\, L_1[\psi,\bar{\psi}]$ such that its Euler-Lagrange derivative gives $E[\psi,\bar\psi] = \frac{\delta S_1}{\delta\bar{\psi}} = \left[ |\psi|^2 \psi \right]_{xx}$, and by conjugation symmetry $\bar{E}[\psi,\bar\psi] = \frac{\delta S_1}{\delta\psi} = \left[ |\psi|^2 \bar{\psi} \right]_{xx}$? The Euler-Lagrange derivative has the general form $\frac{\delta S_1[\psi,\bar{\psi}]}{\delta \bar{\psi}} = \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \bar{\psi}} - \partial_i \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial(\partial_i\bar{\psi})} + \partial_i\partial_j \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial(\partial_i\partial_j\bar{\psi})} - \cdots$, and analogously for $\psi$.

If that were the case, then the linearizations of $E[\psi,\bar{\psi}]$ and $\bar{E}[\psi,\bar\psi]$ would constitute a formally self-adjoint linear differential operator (exercise!). That is, we would have
\begin{multline*}
  \int dx\,dt\, \left(\bar{\phi} \dot{E}[\psi,\bar{\psi}; \xi,\bar{\xi}] + \phi \dot{\bar{E}}[\psi,\bar{\psi}; \xi,\bar{\xi}]\right)
\\  =
  \int dx\,dt\, \left(\dot{E}[\psi,\bar{\psi}; \phi,\bar{\phi}] \bar{\xi} + \dot{\bar{E}}[\psi,\bar{\psi}; \phi,\bar{\phi}] \xi\right) ,
\end{multline*}
whenever $\xi,\bar{\xi}, \phi, \bar{\phi}$ are all smooth and compactly supported, where
\begin{align*}
  E[\psi+\epsilon\xi,\bar{\psi}+\epsilon\bar{\xi}]
  &= E[\psi,\bar{\psi}] + \epsilon \dot{E}[\psi,\bar{\psi}; \xi,\bar{\xi}] + O(\epsilon^2) , \\
  \bar{E}[\psi+\epsilon\xi,\bar{\psi}+\epsilon\bar{\xi}]
  &= \bar{E}[\psi,\bar{\psi}] + \epsilon \dot{\bar{E}}[\psi,\bar{\psi}; \xi,\bar{\xi}] + O(\epsilon^2) .
\end{align*}

In your case,
\begin{align*}
  \left[ |\psi+\epsilon\xi|^2 (\psi+\epsilon\xi) \right]_{xx}
  &= \left[ |\psi|^2 \psi \right]_{xx}
    + \epsilon \left[ 2|\psi|^2 \xi + \bar{\xi} \psi^2 \right]_{xx} + O(\epsilon^2), \\
  \left[ |\psi+\epsilon\xi|^2 (\bar{\psi}+\epsilon\bar{\xi}) \right]_{xx}
  &= \left[ |\psi|^2 \bar{\psi} \right]_{xx}
    + \epsilon \left[ 2|\psi|^2 \bar{\xi} + \xi \bar{\psi}^2 \right]_{xx} + O(\epsilon^2) .
\end{align*}
But then,
\begin{multline*}
  \int dx\,dt\, \left(
    \bar{\phi} \left[ 2|\psi|^2 \xi + \bar{\xi} \psi^2 \right]_{xx}
  + \phi \left[ 2|\psi|^2 \bar{\xi} + \xi \bar{\psi}^2 \right]_{xx} \right)
\\ =
  \int dx\,dt\, \left(
    [2|\psi|^2 \phi_{xx} + \psi^2 \bar{\phi}_{xx}] \bar{\xi}
  + [2|\psi|^2 \bar{\phi}_{xx} + \bar{\psi}^2 \phi_{xx}] \xi
  \right)
\end{multline*}

Obviously, (the linearizations of) your $E[\psi,\bar{\psi}]$ and $\bar{E}[\psi,\bar{\psi}]$ do not satisfy the necessary formal self-adjointness condition. Hence, no such $S_1[\psi,\phi]$ functional exists.

If your modified Schroedinger equation cannot be obtained from a variational principle, then Noether's theorem no longer applies and you cannot deduce the existence of conserved currents from the existence of symmetries.

Comment: I've worked out similar mathematical statements and have grown to the opinion that it is impossible to encode this term into a functional. However, it was extremely helpful to read your exposition. So, thanks a bunch for taking the time to write all of this out!